# rsaJsonWebKey.toJson throws ClassCastException on FIPS enabled host

Tags: fips, jose4j

`Jose4j` up to and including version 0.9.4 throws a `ClassCastException` on the `toJson` method when running the following code on a `FIPS` enabled host.
If you disable `FIPS` on the host, this same code does not throw an error.
We tested using `CentOs` Stream 8, and enabled `FIPS` using the 'fips-mode-setup --enable' command.

```
RsaJsonWebKey rsaJsonWebKey = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);
rsaJsonWebKey.setAlgorithm("RS256");
rsaJsonWebKey.setKeyId("authServer");
rsaJsonWebKey.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.INCLUDE_PRIVATE);
```

The offending line is org.jose4j.jwk.RsaJsonWebKey.getRsaPrivateKey(RsaJsonWebKey.java:124) which reads:

```
  return (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey;
```

When `FIPS` is enabled, 'privateKey' is a 'sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11PrivateKey'
(SunPKCS11-NSS-FIPS RSA private key, 2048 bitssession object, sensitive, extractable) and it will not cast to RSAPrivateKey

When FIPS is not enabled,

```
privateKey' is a 'sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl 
(SunRsaSign RSA private CRT key, 2048 bits)
```

and it will cast to `RSAPrivateKey`

Thanks,
Dmil Team

We expected to not have an exception when running with or without `FIPS` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jose4j's JWK functionality doesn't support outputting the parameters for RSA Private Keys when in this FIPS mode. Whether or not it should is a different/larger question. It does say 'extractable' there but I'd say that typically in a FIPS environment you don't want to be encoding your raw private key in JSON anyway. Changing that last line to `rsaJsonWebKey.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.PUBLIC_ONLY)` will only output the public key parameters and avoid the exception. And the private key object can be accessed using `rsaJsonWebKey.getPrivateKey()`.